# How to reference database name in storedstored procedures?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have an application which i use to connect to two different database both have sync stored procedures and stuff besides the data. Currently have these two different servers but i want to bring them into one and rename the databases. But i have small problem where my stored procedures references to databases for example,

**select * from DatabaseA.Table1**

I want to control the database from the application config so i just have to change the connection string.

```
<add key="DatabaseName" value="DatabaseA"/>
   or 
<add key="DatabaseName" value="DatabaseB"/>
```

Comment: Not 100% sure I understand, but it seems like synonyms could help here (from DatabaseA pointing to objects in DatabaseB and vice versa).

Comment: Yes, changing connection works, but some of the stored procedures fails because its reference in where clauses

Comment: You tagged your queestion with two database management systems: SQL Server and MySQL. Are you actually using both of those?

Comment: Sorry no just sql-server

Comment: Use OPENQUERY to access/update data from a remote server. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx

Comment: You may want to create a new SQL Instance for one of the databases.  There would be two instances on one windows server.  You then might have to just change the linked servers.   Do you want to just make it work or do you want to change the code to eliminate the static naming problem you have encountered within your stored procs.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on my comment on synonyms -

In DatabaseA, create synomyms pointing to objects in DatabaseB and vice versa, like this:

```
USE DatabaseA
GO
CREATE SYNONYM dbo.otherdb_table1 FOR DatabaseB.dbo.table1
GO
CREATE SYNONYM dbo.otherdb_table2 FOR DatabaseB.dbo.table2
GO
...

USE DatabaseB
GO
CREATE SYNONYM dbo.otherdb_table1 FOR DatabaseA.dbo.table1
GO
CREATE SYNONYM dbo.otherdb_table2 FOR DatabaseA.dbo.table2
GO
...
```

This way, you can always reference the table in the *second* database like

```
select col1, col2 from dbo.otherdb_table1
```

This will work regardless of where you create the stored procedure, being it DatabaseA or DatabaseB the stored procedure can be the same.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but what if stored procedures which are joining different databases ?

Answer (score 0):

What I've done in the past is the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test
    @dbName varchar(150)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SqlStatement VARCHAR(MAX)
    SELECT @SqlStatement = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @dbName + '.SchemaName.TableName'
    EXEC sp_executesql @SqlStatement;
END
GO
```

This basically allows you to pass in the dbName to the stored proc and use it however you would like. You could even further pass in the table name if you want that to be dynamic too.

One of the major caveat with this is that you need to make sure to guard against SQL Injection and there is no validation done this approach.

You can give this article a read if you are confused about SQL Injections: http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

However, for the purpose of what you are trying to achieve, I don't believe that injections would be a problem, it's just something to keep in mind.

**UPDATE 1:**
Considering that you don't want to pass in a variable to each of your stored proc's the only other alternative that I can think of is to do the following:

- Create different stored proc's (which reference the different database/s that you want).
- Then control the different stored proc name from config.

Comment: For the purposes of what the OP is trying to do though, it doesn't seem like he would be expecting user input for the stored proc (at least for the dbName) as such, this should be sufficient

Comment: By doing this would require me to change all the sp to pass the additional parameter

Comment: Since you want to control which database the stored proc is running off of from config, I really don't see how else you would do it. The only other method that I could think of is if you create different stored proc's (which reference the different database/s that you want), and then control the different stored proc name from config. (see updated answer)